# Issues presenting UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to give a share screen throughout my app. I am using `UIActivityViewController` for that purpose. The problem is, as per your location in the app, the current root view controller can be of kind `UINavigationController`(Case1) or `UIViewController`(Case2).

I can present `UIActivityViewController` using

```
[viewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I have to get currently visible `UIViewController` of `UINavigationController` in (Case1), and root view controller itself in (Case2).

But how to detect which kind of root view controller is present & code accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UIViewController *root = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];
```

and then:

```
if ([root isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    // Navigation Controller
} else {
    // The other one
}
```

that should tell you which one is presented.

Comment: Using [root presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil] gives error Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x114422630>  on <_UIModalItemAppViewController: 0x111d59ae0> which is already presenting <_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController: 0x111d65ba0>

Comment: That is because you are displaying a VC too early after dismissing one. Put the dismissing of the previous one in completion handler and after that is done, present the new one.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point. I am presenting UIViewController modally on UINavigationController. Then user click on a button I call UIActivityViewController. So there seem to be no transition isuues, since it is already complete.

Comment: The point is, that the code I posted is not the problem causing the error to pop up. The error can pop up for many reasons - bad transition, badly linked IBActions or badly presenting modal VC (for example presenting it twice).

Comment: Are you using `pushViewController:animated` with UINavigationController to show the UIViewControllers? Or perhaps I'm missing something. When you say  "root view controller itself" are you saying the navigation controller will have been removed view hierarchy attached to `keyWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the above method to detect for a UINavigationControler;

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
//If this will be called it is a navigation controller
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use performselector to start and stop rorating activity indicater

Here AI is activity indicater variable name

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateAI) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopAI) withObject:self afterDelay:0.9];

-(void)animateAI
{
    [AI startAnimating];

}

-(void)stopAI
{
   [AI stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: The question is about `UIActivityViewController`. You are talking about `UIActivityIndicatorView`. *Different* stuff.